# What is dot something followed by something without dot in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

For example,

```
.foo bar
.foo bam {
    <key, values>
    ... ...
}
```

I know .foo selects the "foo" class, but what about the bar and bam? Are they descendants of "foo"? And bar, bam share the key values inside the curly braces?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the styling will only be applied to the "bar" and "bam" elements that are inside of the element with the "foo" class.

```
<div class="foo">
  <bar>...</bar>
</div>

<div class="meal">
  <bam>...</bam>
</div>
```

In this example only the "bar" element will get your styling. "bam" would not get the styling since it is not withing an element with a class of "foo".

Comment: Not quite, there is no comma there. They are all children.

Answer (score 2):

Those things following the initial selectors are descendants of the HTML node.

For example:

```
.my-class img {
     width: 50px;
     height: 50px;
}
```

Would affect `img` in:

```
<div class="my-class">
    <img src="myImage.png"/>
</div>
```

Would not affect `img` in:

```
<div class="my-other-class">
    <img src="myImage.png"/>
</div>
```

Comment: @Blender my bad, not completely familiar with the extremely specific terminology.

Comment: Replace "children" with "descendants" and your answer is all good. `>` is the child combinator. Whitespace is the descendant combinator.

Comment: Thanks, seems like it is the same as .foo > bam (== .foo bam). How about, .foo bam, .foo bar {...}, does that mean they() share the same attributes?

Comment: So, space mean descendants and > means direct child?

Comment: @Blender thanks for the note, did not know that! Interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Your CSS:

```
.foo bar .foo bam {
    <key, values>
    ... ...
}
```

(note, there is no comma) selects elements similar to the following:

```
<div class="foo"> 
    <bar>
       <div class="foo">
           <bam>some stuff...</bam>
       </div>
    </bar>
</div>
```